# create-react-app doesn't generating public and src folders and showing a warning UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am beginner to react.. Trying to `create-react-app`.

create-react-app doesn't generate `public` and `src` folders thus cannot get started.

I have created react project using below steps:

```
npx create-react-app new
cd new
npm start
```

Versions:-

```
"Node": 12.18.2
"npm": 6.14.7
```

Dependencies

```
    "cra-template": "1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
```

[image: This is the output of command prompt]

[image: This is the output of files which are created.]

Comment: Can you share warning and error screenshots?

Comment: You might not need to use CRA if that's what prevents you from getting started. https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: Did you tried creating a new app today?I can see the screenshots you have shared are not the latest one

Comment: Ya I tried and got the same output.. That's why shared the old screenshot..